# Unable to reach any device on LAN

Tags: networking, lan, connection

For some time now I've been having problems connecing to other devices on the LAN with my Laptop (Lenovo ideapad 320-15IKB running Windows 10). There are no problems connecting to the web from this device, but I am completely unable to access any local web page, the router administration page, any shared folder, or even ping the default gateway (this yields a general failure). This is true for any Network I'm in, so it must be a problem with my Laptop...

What is even more weird, when I boot up a vm (kali 2019.4 on VirtualBox in my case) these problems disappear. I am suddenly able to open local pages and ping the router from the same device, just by using a virtual machine.

I am completely lost as to what the problem may be, and any help would be highly appreciated. There have been a couple of similar questions posted on superuser, but none of those answers helped me in any way.

Here is my route table, if it is of any help

```
D:\>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 16...34 d4 59 a2 b2 90 ......TAP-NordVPN Windows Adapter V9
  4...8c 16 45 51 f0 bc ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
 14...........................NordLynx Tunnel
  3...0a 00 27 00 00 03 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
 15...b2 fc 36 55 7f 63 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
 25...b0 fc 36 55 7f 63 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #4
 13...00 ff 58 32 91 1a ......Kaspersky Security Data Escort Adapter
 24...00 ff c9 dd 13 75 ......Kaspersky Security Data Escort Adapter #2
 22...b0 fc 36 55 7f 63 ......Realtek 8821AE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.16.142.1   172.16.142.140     55
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.1        10.8.0.15      3
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.8.0.15    259
        10.8.0.15  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.8.0.15    259
       10.8.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.8.0.15    259
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.1        10.8.0.15      3
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     169.254.57.70    261
    169.254.57.70  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.57.70    261
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.57.70    261
     172.16.142.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    172.16.142.140    311
   172.16.142.140  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.16.142.140    311
   172.16.142.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.16.142.140    311
   185.220.70.227  255.255.255.255     172.16.142.1   172.16.142.140     55
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    172.16.142.140    311
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     169.254.57.70    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.8.0.15    259
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    172.16.142.140    311
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.57.70    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.8.0.15    259
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Have you tried to reset Windows 10 Winsock ? Close everything up in Windows. Then from an elevated command prompt (open "Run" type CMD.exe) then in the command prompt type __netsh winsock reset__ then close command prompt, then reboot. It is important to reboot.

Comment: Already tried that, aswell as resetting with ipconfig, but none of that worked...